# Want to play YouTube video with embed code into webview with html content display in same webview

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I have problem to displaying the youtube video with embed code into webview. I am gettinng the html content from webservice with imagess and some text content. Having also youtube embed video code in it. I have successfully display with image and text in it but when youtube embed code comes it will show error like "webpage not available".

So any one having solved this issue before then reply here.

```
WebView wvDesc = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvDesc);
wvDesc.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wvDesc.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

final String mimeType = "text/html";
final String encoding = "UTF-8";
wvDesc.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, strContent, mimeType, encoding, null);
// where strContent is string which is html content need to display the text and youtube video
```

Answer (score 0):

am not sure if this is what you need. Anyway I hope the following be useful. You can use the iframe method that youtube provides to play its videos. If the browser supports html5 will show the video with it, otherwise with flash.

You can use the following code as an example

in the above example the video id is bIPcobKMB94. You can change this id and show your video.

You can access a live example of it here

More infromation for youtube iframe

YouTube HTML5 Video Player

Comment: let me explain you this by this example 

Suppose here is one link having youtube video in it

http://www.uwilldaily.com/uwd-fashion-25-ways-wear-scarf-stylishly/

I want to display this into my android webview same as it display in web browser. Please let me know if you get my problem and yes then give a proper solution